# How to use CTE recursion to get a running total of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have been researching CTE recursion, but I still seem to be confused.

I have table: utb(date, b_id, v_id, b_vol)

I need to get the running total of the column: b_vol.

The catch is that I need to divide if the row_number is even, and multiply if it is odd, so essentially:

> P1= b_vol1, P2 = b_vol1/b_vol2, P3= b_vol1/b_vol2*b_vol3, 
>   P4= b_vol1/b_vol2*b_vol3/b_vol4

So, it is basically P(n)= (P(n-1)(*OR/(b_vol(n))

I can't seem to figure out how to put that into a query.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I hope you can help.

[image: Desired Output(Column SV is what I was referring to as P)]

Comment: show some input data and the expected output.

Comment: In this case just don't bother, make a simple cursor which will be much more clear than revcursive cte.

Comment: @vkp I have added the desired output. Column (SV) is the only new column, so the other columns are the original input.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I will have to look into what a cursor is, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sample table only has 1 column B_VOL. Try this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE ( B_VOL int)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (50), (50), ( 50), (50) ,(155), (255)

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT sd.*, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) - 1 AS RowIndex FROM @SampleData sd
)
,cte AS
(
   SELECT TOP 1  t.RowIndex, CAST( t.B_VOL  AS decimal(18,7)) AS sv FROM temp t ORDER BY t.RowIndex ASC
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.RowIndex, CAST(cte.sv * (CASE WHEN t.RowIndex % 2 = 1 THEN CAST(1 AS decimal(18,7))/t.B_VOL ELSE t.B_VOL  END) AS  decimal(18,7)) AS sv                                 
   FROM  cte 
   INNER JOIN temp t ON cte.RowIndex + 1 = t.RowIndex 
)
SELECT  t.*, c.sv
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN cte c ON t.RowIndex = c.RowIndex
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: This basically did the trick! There were some precision things I had to touch up, but other than that your recursion worked wonders. I am going to study it :D. Thanks triV!

Comment: you hv one extra inner join in last

Answer (score 0):

First, a CTE is not the best way to solve this problem.  But . . .

```
with u as (
      select u.*, row_number() over (order by date) - 1 as seqnum
      from utb u
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, b_vol as result
      from u
      union all
      select cte.seqnum, cte.result * (case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then 1.0 / b_vol else b_vol end) as result
      from cte join
           u
           on u.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. I got the above query to give a result, but it is not calculating anything. The result column is just printing out the b_vol value. Any ideas?

Comment: @UncleJesse . . . .Possibly because `b_vol` is an integer.  You may need to cast to a numeric type of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this,

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE ( B_VOL int)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (50), (50), ( 50), (50) ,(155), (255)

;with CTE as
(
select S.B_VOL,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by ((select null)))rn
from @SampleData S
)
,CTE1 AS
(
select b_vol,cast(b_vol as float) sv,1 rn1 
from cte    where rn=1

union ALL

select c.b_vol,
case when (c1.rn1+1)%2=0
THEN c1.sv/cast(c.b_vol as float)
ELSE
c1.sv*cast(c.b_vol as float)
end
,c1.rn1+1
from CTE C
inner join CTE1 c1
on c.rn=c1.rn1+1
where c1.rn1<7
)

select * from cte1
```